# How to mock a node field value for phpunit?

Tags: 8, testing

I'm working on a project where we need to have code coverage using phpunit.

I have a method that includes this code:

```
  $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($node_id);

  $form['data-title']['#value'] = $node->label();

  $form['data-description']['#value'] = $node->field_description->value;
```

So I need to mock out the node object.

I can get the node label to work, but not the field_description->value

Here's my set up function in my test class:

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    $container = new Container();
    $container->set('string_translation', $this->getStringTranslationStub());

    $renderer = $this->getMockBuilder(Renderer::class)
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
    $renderer
      ->method('render')
      ->willReturn('Hello world');

    $container->set('renderer', $renderer);

    // Mock entity type manager.
    $this->entityTypeManager = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityTypeManagerInterface::class)
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();

    // Mock a node and add the label to it.
    $node = $this->getMockBuilder(Node::class)
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
    $node->expects($this->any())
      ->method('label')
      ->willReturn('shaken not stirred');

    $node->expects($this->any())
      ->method('access')
      ->willReturn(TRUE);

    $node->expects($this->any())
      ->method('id')
      ->willReturn(1);


    // @todo figure out how to add a field to a mock node.
    /*$field_description = new \stdClass();

    $field_description->value = 'This is a description';

    $node->set('field_description', $field_description);*/


    $node_storage = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityStorageInterface::class)
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
    $node_storage->expects($this->any())
      ->method('load')
      ->willReturn($node);
    $this->entityTypeManager->expects($this->any())
      ->method('getStorage')
      ->willReturn($node_storage);

    $this->uuid = $this->getMockBuilder(UuidInterface::class)
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();

    $container->set('entity_type.manager', $this->entityTypeManager);

    $entity_repository = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
    $entity_repository->expects($this->any())
      ->method('getTranslationFromContext')
      ->willReturn($node);

    $container->set('entity.repository', $entity_repository);

    \Drupal::setContainer($container);
    $this->form = MyForm::create($container);

  }
```

Comment: If you are doing a UnitTestCase and find yourself doing too many crazy mocks, you probably need to think about doing a KernelTestBase test.

Comment: Also, using get() instead of relying on  the magic __get() should make mocking a bit easier, but mocking content entities is hard as they are very complex structures. Agree that it might be better to write a kernel test

Comment: For this project we're required to use unit testing.  I'm not sure KernelTestBase would count.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following should work using PHPUnit Mock Objects as in your example.

First mock FieldItemListInterface __get magic method.

```
$fieldDescMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface')
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
$fieldDescMock->expects($this->any())
  ->method('__get')
  ->with('value')
  ->willReturn('blah');
```

Then mock the Node/ContentEntityBase __get magic method.

```
$node->expects($this->any())
  ->method('__get')
  ->with('field_description')
  ->willReturn($fieldDescMock);
```

Comment: Awesome, this was very helpful!  It worked exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: You might look into prophecy, which _might_ work with magic methods, but not static methods. It would help reduce the verbosity of the unit tests. It's a a bit of out scope of this question/answer and "opinionated" so I didn't want to mention it directly.

Comment: @mradcliffe, would you be able to provide an example using prophecy ?

Answer (score 4):

[Mradcliffe's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/267935/45409) worked for me, here's my example code:

Here's what ended up working for me:

```
$this->node = $this->getMockBuilder(Node::class)
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();

$fieldAdsEnabled = $this->getMockBuilder(FieldItemListInterface::class)
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
$fieldAdsEnabled->expects($this->any())
  ->method('__get')
  ->with('value')
  ->willReturn(1);
$this->node->expects($this->any())
  ->method('__get')
  ->with('field_widgets_enabed')
  ->willReturn($fieldAdsEnabled);
```

Note: for me using Node object and not NodeInterface helped.  I suspect because otherwise __get isn't available.